# Can anyone give guidance on installing TFS Build on a Windows Azure Role

Tags: azure, tfsbuild

We have TFS 2010 working on-premise in a domain environment.

I want to add a Build Service which will be hosted in a multi-instance Azure service wherein the build agent runs in the cloud. It will have access to SourceControl from on-prem TFS probably through Service Bus. I would prefer to do this without using a VM Role if possible.

The most likely topology as per [Understanding a Team Foundation BuildSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793166%28VS.100%29.aspx) is either the 'Multiple-machine System' or 'Multiple-machine system with multiple controllers'

Has anyone done this specific type of deployment, how?
Could the Build Agent be made to run in a Web or Worker role?

Comment: Does this help? Not quite the same, but could be better suited: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/14/team-foundation-server-on-windows-azure.aspx

Comment: I knew MS were working on TFS on Azure, but from the link above: "(though for now you will need to set up a TFS 11 CTP build agent on your own hardware)".  It seems even they haven't figured out how to do it nicely yet.

Comment: Curious, why do you want to use a web/worker role?

Comment: Think they want a web/worker role because it's cheaper.

Comment: The reason for wanting a build server in Azure was to get over the issues related to getting a build server set up internally. Optionallys, it would also have given us some more scalability as we needed it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the tfs preview it can be done using the vm role: http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/10/running-your-build-server-on-azure.html